# Vowel substring

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I have to write a program that takes a String as user input and then prints a substring that starts with the first vowel of the String and ends with the last. So for instance if my String is : "Hi I have a dog named Patch", the printed substring would be : "i I have a dog named Pa"

This is the code I have now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class SousChaineVoyelle {
    private static Scanner sc;
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        
        int pos1 = 0;
        int pos2 = 0;
        int i;
        int j;
        
        boolean isVowel1 = false;
        
        boolean isVowel2 = false;
        
        
        for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if (str.charAt(i) == 'A' || str.charAt(i) == 'a' || 
            chaine.charAt(i) == 'E' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || 
            str.charAt(i) == 'I' || str.charAt(i) == 'i' || 
            str.charAt(i) == 'O' || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || 
            str.charAt(i) == 'U' || str.charAt(i) == 'u' || 
            str.charAt(i) == 'Y' || str.charAt(i) == 'y'){
            isVowel1 = true;
            break;
            }           
        }
        if (isVowel1){
            pos1 = str.charAt(i);
        }
        
        for (j = str.length() - 1; j > i; j--){
            if (str.charAt(j) == 'A' || str.charAt(j) == 'a' || 
            str.charAt(j) == 'E' || str.charAt(j) == 'e' || 
            str.charAt(j) == 'I' || str.charAt(j) == 'i' || 
            str.charAt(j) == 'O' || str.charAt(j) == 'o' || 
            str.charAt(j) == 'U' || str.charAt(j) == 'u' || 
            str.charAt(j) == 'Y' || str.charAt(j) == 'y'){
            isVowel2 = true;
            break;
            }
        }
        if (isVowel2){
                pos2 = str.charAt(j);
        }
        
        
                
        String sub = chaine.substring(pos1, pos2);
        
        System.out.print(The substring from the first vowel to the last is  "\"" + sub +"\"");
    }
}

this got me this:
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 22 out of bounds for length 22
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:106)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:302)
at java.base/java.lang.String.checkIndex(String.java:4557)
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:46)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:1515)
at SousChaineVoyelle.main(SousChaineVoyelle.java:33)

Comment: You  need to break the loop when you see a vowel.

Comment: Where would you put the break though. I tried putting it inside the if statement but its telling me im out of bounds

Comment: right after vowel1=true and vowel2=true.

Comment: I updated what i modified in my code but its still telling me this:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [111, 111) out of bounds for length 22

Comment: i dont understand how i can be out of bounds when i specified that 'i' is smaller then the length

Comment: you pos1 and ps2 should just be i and j.

Comment: pos1 = s.charAt(i) would gives you the ascii code of the character at i. this is not what you want.  you just want i.

Comment: it finally worked thank you so much

Comment: Your code would be a lot cleaner with a dedicated `isVowel(char c)` method, the body of which could be something like `return "AEIOUY".indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(c)) > -1;`

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking at it is you have a lot of code to do a simple thing, which means more chances for bugs and errors.

Here's a "less code" solution:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)^[^aeiou]*|[^aeiou]*$", "");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/qKQgve).

This works by matching all leading and trailing non-vowels (if any) and replacing them with nothing, effectively deleting them.
`(?i)` makes the match case insensitive.

Comment: thank you. That's practical. I gotta be honest, I'm just starting coding so all this is very new to me

Answer (score 0):

After the first for loop, i will be str.length() no matter what. You may want to create another variable to hold I when it's found to remedy this.